# Reimbursement for municipal and water taxes when leaving mid-year?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, payment, utilities, amsterdam

Alas, I've left the Netherlands... Tot ziens, mijn mooie thuis weg van huis...

Now, I was living in Amsterdam, I left in mid-year (June), after having paid the full year's municipal taxes (WOZ-beschikking gebruiker and Afvalstoffenheffing)
and the yearly water charge (Waterschapsbelasting) to WaterNet.

My question: Can I get a refund for the relative part of the year in which I had already left? If so, is there some specific procedure for making such a request, or do I just go on their respective websites and use the contact form to ask?

Comment: As you can see I've done some research regarding Waternet, but this is a lot of work. My advice would be to follow you own suggestion and just ask them.

Comment: @JanDoggen: You got your +1... I was hoping someone has actually done something like this and could tell me "Do X then Y then Z" or "It can't be done".

Answer (score 3):

From [Waternet](https://www.waternet.nl/veelgestelde-vragen/belasting/verandert-mijn-aanslag-bij-een-verhuizing/):

> Vertrekt u uit Nederland? Geef uw nieuwe adres door aan één van de 19 gemeentes waar dit kan. De gemeente stuurt uw gegevens ook naar ons door. Meestal verlagen wij uw aanslag. Hierover krijgt u dan vanzelf bericht van ons.

Google translate:

> Are you leaving the Netherlands? Pass on your new address to one of the 19 municipalities<sup>*</sup> where this is possible. The municipality also sends your data to us. We usually lower your bill. You will automatically receive a message from us about this.

The [page about adjusting the bill](https://www.waternet.nl/service-en-contact/waterschapsbelasting/verlaging-aanslag-belasting/) mentions:

> U betaalt minder zuiveringsheffing als u vertrekt uit ons gebied. U hoeft namelijk alleen zuiveringsheffing te betalen voor de periode dat u op uw oude adres woonde. U krijgt op uw nieuwe adres ook een brief hierover.
> De hoogte van de watersysteemheffing ingezetenen blijft gelijk. Dit is voor ieder huishouden een vast bedrag per jaar. Ook als u verhuist. We kijken hierbij naar uw situatie op 1 januari.

Google translate:

> You pay less pollution tax when you leave our area. You only have to pay a levy for the period that you lived at your old address. You will also receive a letter about this at your new address. 
> The level of the water system levy for residents remains the same. This is a fixed amount per year for each household. Even if you move. We look at your situation on 1 January.

I read this as that you may get some money back from the 'zuiveringsheffing' but not from the 'watersysteemheffing'.

That *19 municipalities* refers to a [goverment page](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/privacy-en-persoonsgegevens/vraag-en-antwoord/waar-registratie-niet-ingezetenen-rni) about registration in the *Basisregistratie Personen (BRP)*. Lower down the page it links to [Wanneer moet ik mij uit de Basisregistratie Personen (BRP) laten uitschrijven?](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/privacy-en-persoonsgegevens/vraag-en-antwoord/uitschrijven-basisregistratie-personen):

> Wanneer moet ik mij uit de Basisregistratie Personen (BRP) laten uitschrijven?
>
> U moet zich laten uitschrijven als ingezetene uit de Basisregistratie Personen (BRP) als u in een jaar tijd langer dan 8 maanden in het buitenland verblijft.

Google translate:

> When do I have to deregister from the Basic Person Registration (BRP)?
>
> You must deregister as a resident (...) if you stay abroad for more than 8 months in a year.

I assume you already know (how) you have to do that.

<sup>* [Amsterdam is one of those 19](https://www.amsterdam.nl/veelgevraagd/?productid=%7BE3E7C543-D4AA-4D28-99DD-1CA42D84919C%7D)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Update as things progress:

- In late September, WaterNet sent me a letter, informing me my annual service charge was being reduced by 55.08 EUR. So, apparently they got informed at some point about my de-registration. However - the total charge had been 269.56 EUR, and I left after 169 of 364 days of the year, so that din't make sense. I've written them to inquire about the details.
- No news from the Municipality yet, I've written them through IAmsterdam.nl 's contact form.